# Wordpress Gallery not being output correctly/consistently

Tags: gallery

Using WP 3.5.0, Wordpress galleries have been working fine.  I use the Cleaner Gallery plugin and Lightbox to display galleries in lightbox mode.

Now I am using WP 3.5.1, a gallery I created on [this page](http://test.incredibleconcepts.com.au/inflatables/archways/) is output with inconsistant hyperlinks on the thumbnails.

Some point to a URL with format:
http://test.incredibleconcepts.com.au/?attachment_id=2593

Some point to a URL with format:
http://test.incredibleconcepts.com.au/exhibitions/inflatable_archway_06/

Both fail to load larger images in the lightbox, producing message "image cannot be loaded, please check the image filename and path and try again".

To me, the hyperlinks on the thumbnails are not correct, but I can't see why Wordpress would be producing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have the gallery settings pointing to the attachment pages instead of the media files directly.

You can try this shortcode

```
[gallery size="full" link="file"]
```

instead of the default

```
[gallery]
```

if you want different sizes, you can change the **size** parameter to size="thumb", size="medium", size="large" or to the image-size-name you want to use.

Comment: Thanks birgire.  I was choosing to link to the file when creating the gallery, but link="file" was not added to the shortcode.  The same symptom has occurred for a 2nd gallery.